# Concentration compactness lemma and the best Sobolev constant

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, measure-concentration

It is well known that the best Sobolev constant can be achieved on $\mathbf{R}^n$. More precisely, we have the following theorem (A):

- Let $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$, $$S=\inf\limits_{{u\in H^1(\mathbf{R}^n)}}\frac{\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}|Du|^2 dx}{(\int _{\mathbf{R}^n}|u|^{q} dx)^{\frac{2}{q}}}.$$
  Suppose $(u_m)$ is a minimizing sequence for $S$ with $ \|u_{m}\|_{L^q}=1$. Then $(u_m)$ up to translation and dilation is relatively compact.

I'm confused about the necessity of translation. The proof of the theorem is based on the concentration function with a probability measure $\mu$:
$$Q(r):=\sup_{x\in \mathbf{R}^n}\mu(B_{R}(x)).$$

For a sequence probability measures $\mu_{m}$, we have the corresponding concentration functions $Q_m$. By Helly' Lemma, up to a subsequence, we obtain $Q_m(R)\to Q(R)$ for a.e. $R$. Let
$$\lambda : = \lim_{R\to \infty} Q(R) .$$

Then based on the value of $\lambda$ we divided the three cases happen:

- (Compactness $\lambda=1$)
- (Vanishing $\lambda=0$)
- (Dichotomy $\lambda\in(0,1)$)

In Struwe's book Variational Methods page 46, he chooses $x_{m}, R_{m}>0$ such that for the rescaled sequence
$$v_{m}(x)= R_{m}^{-\frac{n}{q}}u_{m}(\frac{x-x_{m}}{R_m}),$$
so that the corresponding concentration functions
$$Q_m(1) = \sup_{x\in \mathbf{R}^n} \int _{B_1(x)} |v_m|^q dx =\frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence the vanishing case is ruled out. And actually, he proves that $(v_m)$ is relatively compact in $H^{1}(\mathbf{R}^n)$.

Thanks to Willie Wong,  he gives an example showing that translation is necessary. Also thanks to Leo Moos, who helps me find my mistakes.

- Correction： If we consider the function  with a probability measures $\mu$:

$$\hat{Q}(R)=  \mu(B_{R}(0)).$$
Then there are still only three cases that happen. Moreover, for some $\hat{R}_{m}>0$, consider the rescaled sequence
$$\hat{v}_{m}(x)= \hat{R}_{m}^{-\frac{n}{q}}u_{m}(\frac{x}{\hat{R}_m}),$$
up to a subsequence, we assume $\hat{v}_{m} \to v$ weakly.
It seems that we still have
$$\hat{Q}_m(1) =  \int _{B_1(0)} |\hat{v}_m|^q dx =\frac{1}{2}.$$
Then similarly the vanishing is ruled out. The same calculations as in Struwe's book yield that the dichotomy case doesn't happen. So we only need to consider the compactness case:
$$\hat{\lambda}:= \lim_{R\to \infty} \hat{Q}(R)=1.$$
Then using the concentration-Compactness Lemma $2$ in Struwe'book, we finally obtain two cases happen:

- (1) $v=0$ and $|\hat{v}_m|^q dx$ converges to a Dirac measure weakly.
- (2) $\|v\|_{L^q}=1 $ and eventually $(\hat{v}_m)$ is relatively compact in $H^{1}(\mathbf{R}^n)$.

Since $\hat{\lambda}=1$ implies that $\lambda=1$ so I didn't check the last step carefully, it seems that if I change the concentration function $Q$ to be $\hat{Q}$, then I can not avoid the case (1) happens.

Comment: If $u_m$ is an arbitrary minimizing sequence, then simply by rescaling you cannot get compactness. Take $w$ to be the known soliton minimizer for the Sobolev embedding. Let $u_m (x) = w(x + m e_1)$ where $e_1$ is the unit vector. Then to ensure the bound on $\hat{Q}_m$ you need $\hat{R}_m\nearrow \infty$, but you can check by hand in this case the functions $\hat{v}_m$ has no Cauchy subsequences.

Comment: (Ignore my first comment; I was confused by what your description of the argument said.)

Comment: @LeoMoos: the idea is that my very explicit counterexample should help the OP track down where exactly his/her mistake is. // Most likely this is in a hidden compactness argument: somewhere along the line (following general CC type arguments), Struwe will need to appeal to a certain type of compactness (either in the form of upgrading certain weak convergence to strong convergence, or directly stating that certain sequence is pre-compact). For the critical Sobolev embedding, you need for that both an upper and lower bound in scale, which can show up in multiple ways. ...

Comment: ... my counterexample shows that the OP's argument, at least for an explicit minimizing sequence, cannot have both an upper and lower bound (it only provides a lower bound, but not upper), which is why it fails. (That a bound on scale is required is due to the failure of Rellich-Kondrachov in the critical case.) But precisely where and how Struwe's argument works in this scale constraint is something that I'm happy to leave to the OP to track down.

Comment: Final comment: observe that in your summary, if $R_m$ is such that $Q_m > \frac12$, then you can replace $R_m$ by anything even larger and still get that property. There **must** be something in Struwe's argument to force $R_m$ not being too big, something that actually constrains $R_m$ from above. If you find that something, you'll find why the pure dilation version will not work.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, I deleted my comment because I wasn't sure whether it was contributing much to the discussion... In any case your reply is spot on - when you rescale your translated sequence to capture the energy in the unit ball, you're going to see concentration. I just flicked through the section in Struwe's book, and he uses compactness of the measures $\lvert u \rvert^q \mathrm{d} x$ and $\lvert D u \rvert^p \mathrm{d} x$, and concludes the argument by showing that their limits don't contain singular (meaning Dirac delta) components. I think this is the part where the [...]

Comment: [...] proposed argument would show its flaws.

Comment: There are much simpler proofs of this. The one I like is the one by Cordero-Nazaret-Villani using optimal transport.